# How to create my own simple autoresponder for Postfix with custom conditions?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

Postfix/Dovecot

I want to create my simple custom autoresponder for Postfix, in Python, for instance. I don't need any third-party ready-to-user one.

I want it to have some custom conditions such as "autoreply only when 'from == A' or/and 'to == B' or/and "there's have been no autoprely to that email today', etc...

I've found out that I'll need to use either content_filter or spawn in master.cf. Not milter, because milter is triggered because a message has been put into a queue, whereas I'll need to autoreply to messages that already have come through. Probably.

Other better options?

How to do implement that?